# Invert binary numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

is there a kind of "logical no" for numpy arrays (of numbers of course).

For example, consider this array:
`x = [1,0,1,0,0,1]`

i am looking for an easy way to compute its "inverse"
`y = [0,1,0,1,1,0]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For an array of `1s` and `0s` you can simply subtract the values in `x` from `1`:

```
x = np.array([1,0,1,0,0,1])
1-x
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

---

Or you could also take the bitwise `XOR` of the binary values in `x` with `1`:

```
x^1 
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: why 1-x? won't some 0 become -1?? is it because of the binary type? e.g. uint8?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `np.logical_not`:

```
np.logical_not(x).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 5):

Or using XOR:

```
y =  [n ^ 1 for n in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
y =  (x == 0).astype(int)
```

Alternatively:

```
y =  0 + (x == 0)
```

Output:

```
[0 1 0 1 1 0]
```

**Notes:**

1. `(x == 0)` gives a boolean array where `False` appears in the place of `1`, and `True` appears in the place of `0`.
2. Calling the method `astype(int)`, or adding scalar `0` to the matrix, converts `False` to `0` and `True` to `1`